# Jersey - Freemarker - use custom ViewProcessor

Tags: jersey, freemarker

My template is rendered but without the freemarker treatments.
the output is

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome ${user}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The variable user has not been replaced by its value.

So I'm not sure Jersey know something about my custom ViewProcessor. How can I say explicitly to Jersey that I want to use the Freemarker ViewProcessor.

I have seen the following sample but it doesn't help
http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C-1697896452

To sum up I have :

in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-freemarker</artifactId>
    <version>1.12</version>
</dependency>
```

in my JerseyServletModule

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("com.sun.jersey.freemarker.templateBasePath", "freemarker");
serve("/*").with(GuiceContainer.class, params);
```

in my TestResource

```
@Path("/test")
@GET
@Produces("text/html")
public Viewable getMytestView() {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("user", "Peter");
    return new Viewable("/test.ftl", map);
}
```

in my src/main/resources/freemarker/test.ftl

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome ${user}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it works now. Sorry, it's certainly a cache problem.